# Simple question about 'floating point exception' in C

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-exceptions

I have the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
double x=0;
double y=0/x;
if (y==1)
  printf("y=1\n");
else
  printf("y=%f\n",y);
if (y!=1)
  printf("y!=1\n");
else
  printf("y=%f\n",y);

return 0;
}
```

The output I get is

```
y=nan
y!=1
```

But when I change the line
    double x=0;
to
    int x=0;
the output becomes

```
Floating point exception
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: When will all these questions about precision, doubles, decimals, and floats ever go away? http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You are dividing by zero ,which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special bit-pattern in IEE754 which indicates `NaN` as the result of *floating point* division by zero errors.

However there's no such representation when using integer arithmetic, so the system has to throw an exception instead of returning `NaN`.

Comment: Okay I see but why is that? Why is floating point division by zero allowed but not by integers?

Comment: because it's possible to detect the `NaN` result of a floating point division after you've done it.  There's no way to do that with an integer result other than by testing for a zero divisor _before_ performing the division.

Answer (score 2):

You're causing the division `0/0` with integer arithmetic (which is invalid, and produces the exception you see). Regardless of the type of `y`, what's evaluated first is `0/x`.

When `x` is declared to be a `double`, the zero is converted to a `double` as well, and the operation is performed using floating-point arithmetic.

When `x` is declared to be an `int`, you are dividing one `int` 0 by another, and the result is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Because due to [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#NaNs), NaN will be produced when conducting an illegal operation on floating point numbers (e.g. `0/0`, `∞×0`, or `sqrt(−1)`).

> There are actually two kinds of NaNs, signaling and quiet. Using a
>   signaling NaN in any arithmetic operation (including numerical
>   comparisons) will cause an "invalid" exception. Using a quiet NaN
>   merely causes the result to be NaN too.
>
> The representation of NaNs specified by the standard has some
>   unspecified bits that could be used to encode the type of error; but
>   there is no standard for that encoding. In theory, signaling NaNs
>   could be used by a runtime system to extend the floating-point numbers
>   with other special values, without slowing down the computations with
>   ordinary values. Such extensions do not seem to be common, though.

Also, Wikipedia says this about [integer division by zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero):

> Integer division by zero is usually handled differently from floating
>   point since there is no integer representation for the result. Some
>   processors generate an exception when an attempt is made to divide an
>   integer by zero, although others will simply continue and generate an
>   incorrect result for the division. The result depends on how division
>   is implemented, and can either be zero, or sometimes the largest
>   possible integer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the min and max values of an integer data type.  You will see that an undefined or nan result is not in it's range.

And read this [what every computer scientist should know about floating point.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

Integer division by 0 is illegal and is not handled. Float values on the other hand are handled in `C` using [NaN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN). The following how ever would work.

```
int x=0;
double y = 0.0 / x;
```

Comment: that is obvious as `y` is now a double.  The op already has that figured out.

Comment: @JonH It might not be as obvious as you think to the OP, especially since the double values were set using literal integer constants. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you divide `int` to `int` you can divide by 0.

`0/0` in doubles is `NaN`.

```
int x=0;
double y=0/x; //0/0 as ints **after that** casted to double. You can use
double z=0.0/x; //or
double t=0/(double)x; // to avoid exception and get NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

Floating point is inherently modeling the reals to limited precision.  There are only a finite number of bit-patterns, but an infinite (continuous!) number of reals.   It does its best of course, returning the closest representable real to the exact inputs it is given.  Answers that are too small to be directly represented are instead represented by zero.  Dividing by zero is an error in the real numbers.  In floating point, however, because zero can arise from these very small answers, it can be useful to consider x/0.0 (for positive x) to be "positive infinity" or "too big to be represented".  This is no longer useful for x = 0.0.

The best we could say is that dividing zero by zero is really "dividing something small that can't be told apart from zero by something small that can't be told apart from zero".  What the answer to this?  Well, there is no answer for the exact case of 0/0, and there is no good way of treating it inexactly.  It would depend on the relative magnitudes, and so the processor basically shrugs and says "I lost all precision -- any result I gave you would be misleading", by returning Not a Number.

In contrast, when doing an integer divide by zero, the divisor really can only mean precisely zero.  There's no possible way to give a consistent meaning to it, so when your code asks for the answer, it really is doing something illegitimate.

(It's an integer division in the second case, but not the first because of the promotion rules of C.  0 can be taken as an integer literal, and as both sides are integers, the division is integer division.  In the first case, the fact that `x` is a double causes the dividend to be promoted to double.  If you replace the `0` by `0.0`, it will be a floating-point division, no matter the type of `x`.)

Comment: Your first paragraph is *extremely* misleading.  The basic arithmetic operations in IEEE-754 floating point treat their arguments as if they were exact.  Zero really means exactly zero.  `0.0/0.0` does not produce a NaN because "it might not be zero"; it produces NaN because there is not a unique number x for which 0 = 0*x.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: Sure, FP treats the inputs as if they were exact, and returns the closest representable real when it exists. But they don't have infinite precision.  A zero can arise in a calculation when the exact answer isn't representable; and this does motivates the treatment for division by zero. Consider the case of x/0 for positive x: it gives +infinity.  This is not because infinity * 0 is any x, but really is instead treating zero as "really small" (and infinity as "really big").  This behavior is useful and makes sense, but stops being so for x = 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's incorrect.  I was being a little fast-and-loose in my comment, but this is still wrong.  Zero is not treated as "really small".  What actually happens is that a/x is mathematically undefined at x = 0, but the function is extended by continuity by taking the limit as x -> 0+.  This limit is taken not in the usual real numbers, but in the two-point compactification of the real numbers, so it is +infinity.  If 0 were merely treated as though it were "really small", then division by zero would signal overflow. However, it does not; the result is an *exact* infinity instead.

Comment: @Stephen Canon: I see the distinction, and you're technically right.  0 is treated exactly as 0, and infinity exactly as infinity.  But the reasons for this choice of working in these extended reals is because 
they nicely capture limiting behavior and continuity of many functions on the reals.  Yes, IEEE signals make a distinction of exactness, but for most purposes it is silly.  In terms of the actual values that are returned, infinities can result from overflows, and 0 from underflows.